# Regex to match around delimiters

Tags: c#, regex

Using the string

`A B x C x D - E x F`

I am trying to capture the groups `A B` `C` and `D` but not `E` or `F`.

My understanding of regex is that I want everything before `\sx\s` up to the `\s-\s`,

so I would start with `.*(?=\sx\s)`,

which I want to happen as many times until I reach the `\s-\s`.

My result is `(.*(?=\sx\s))*.*(?=\s-\s)` which returns `A B x C x D`.

I think this may have to do with the way lookaheads work but I am lost on what to change.

Comment: This is a great question.  You stated your problem and the steps / thought process you took to solve it and are asking why your solution isn't working.  Kudos to you.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/HYQIf6/1 try `([^x\s])(?=.*-.*)`.  Does that work for you?  Or do you want `A B` in one group?

Comment: Try `(\s?([^x]+))\s(?=.*-.*)` if you want `A B` in one group.  See https://regex101.com/r/HYQIf6/3

Comment: These are both incredibly helpful, thank-you!

Comment: If C# supports variable-length lookbehinds you could use `(?<!-.*)[A-Z]`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7683Zq/3/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a positive lookahead `(?=\s-\s)`, the pattern must be present in the data.

If you want to match `AB`, `C` and `D` and also want to match those values if this part `- E x F` is not present, you could make use of a quantifier in a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\s-\s.*)[A-Z](?:\s[A-Z])*
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\s-\s.*)` Negative lookbehind, assert what is on the left is not `\s-\s`
- `[A-Z]` Match a char A-Z
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\s[A-Z]` Math whitespace char followed by A-Z
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cs-%5cs.*%29%5bA-Z%5d%28%3f%3a%5cs%5bA-Z%5d%29*&i=A+B+x+C+x+D+-+E+x+F%0d%0aA+B+x+C+x+D)